# Thunderbird 15 Chat Notification even if my window in minimized

Tags: thunderbird, notifications, instant-messaging, chat

This is my first post on SU. 
My Question is related to thunderbird `15.0.1` I configured the chat accounts which is a great feature, I was wondering whether I could configure or install any add-on if any to get a notification even if my window is minimized or a popup about it.

I hope my question was clear. I could not find this question of existing SU Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone.  It appears this type of notification has been requested.  At the very bottom there is a quick and dirty work around.  In the mean time I would suggest voting for the bug to be fixed.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742746

Comment: Thanks a lot adam, I am for surely vote up for the bug to get solve.

Answer (score 0):

We just released a light addon for chat notifications on Mozilla Addons site: [Chat Notifier (for Thunderbird)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/chat-notifier-for-thunderbid/). It just does what was missing: A sound and a message box.

Tell us what you think, we will be happy to here from you.